# How do I gather integration test coverage reports with the Sonarqube Maven plugin?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am trying to gather code coverage metrics on both unit and integration tests run by Maven following directions linked to by the [SonarQube Maven plugin guide](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven). I believe I have successfully generated coverage metrics with jacoco: I have files `jacoco.exec` and `jacoco-it.exec`, and though I don't know how to look inside them to find useful information, they do have different sizes in accordance with different numbers of unit and integration tests, FWIW.

From there I can run e.g. `mvn sonar:sonar` to upload unit test coverage to my local server, but I have not been able to upload integration test coverage. In my pom file I have a property `<sonar.junit.reportPaths>target/failsafe-reports,target/failsafe-reports</sonar.junit.reportPaths>` which seems to do nothing. I have tried both the latest official and codehaus versions of `sonar-maven-plugin` (version 3.3.0.603). I am using the latest official SonarQube Docker image (v. 6.4) which evidently contains SonarQube Version 6.3.1 according to the SQ UI (why the discrepancy there?).

I noticed in the console output when running `mvn sonar:sonar`, it says

```
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor [java]
[INFO] parsing /home/jason/.../target/surefire-reports
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor [java] (done) | time=57ms
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoSensor [java]
[INFO] Analysing /home/jason/.../target/jacoco-it.exec
[INFO] Analysing /home/jason/.../target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] Analysing /home/jason/.../target/sonar/jacoco-merged.exec
```

so it's picking up both jacoco coverage reports, yet showing only unit tests in the UI. Since that output mentions `target/surefire-reports` but never mentions `failsafe-reports`, as an experiment, I tried copying everything from `failsafe-reports` to `surefire-reports`, and the IT information was present in the SQ UI, but that is a hack, and I found a similar SO question advising configuring failsafe to output to `surefire-reports` to trick SQ in this way.

So my ultimate question is how do I get SQ to upload IT information? Simpler questions are, how do I tell it to parse `failsafe-reports`, and what difference does `sonar.junit.reportPaths` make?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the version of SonarQube

Answer (score 0):

I think this link should have you covered: https://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2012/02/05/separating-integration-and-unit-tests-with-maven-sonar-failsafe-and-jacoco/

Answer (score 0):

It is likely showing a combined number rather than a breakdown. I am having the same issue with gradle. The other answer is referring to an older version of sonarqube. `sonar.phase` property is dropped since  v4.2.

Here's the link to how it is done in more recent version:
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples

I hope this helps.